# External screen recognized, but black

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, 16.10

I have a brand new computer (i5-7200U, so Kabylake with a Intel HD Grpahics 620) running Ubuntu 16.10.

And I use an external HDMI screen.

For some reasons, this one is detected (I see it in the Display parameters menu) but it stays black (with a signal because if not, the monitor would turn off).

At work I have another HDMI screen, and I have no problems with this one. I also tried various cables, but the screen stays black.

This screen is working, since I use it with other computers (Ubuntu 16.10, Hackintosh, Windows).

I'm a bit lost about what can I do to solve this issue. Any ideas ?

Here are some details of my configuration:

```
~ % sudo lshw -c display        
[sudo] Mot de passe de bigx : 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: Intel Corporation
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       ressources: irq:126 mémoire:ee000000-eeffffff mémoire:d0000000-dfffffff portE/S:f000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

So the driver is i915 (from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/ and up to date).

```
~ % modinfo i915         
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Intel Corporation
author:         Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
firmware:       i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin
firmware:       i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin
firmware:       i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin
firmware:       i915/skl_guc_ver6_1.bin
...
```

other outputs:

```
~ % lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5916] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:15a0]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

and

```
~ % xrandr --props              
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff000dae721300000000
        0e1a0104951d1178028785a457509b27
        0d505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101b43b804a71383440503c
        680025a510000018000000fe004e3133
        334843452d454e310a20000000fe0043
        4d4e0a202020202020202020000000fe
        004e3133334843452d454e310a200024
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
   1920x1080     60.01*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
HDMI-2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff004c2d3f0b48385a5a
        081a010380301b782a9561a55552a028
        0f5054bfef80714f81c0810081809500
        a9c0b3000101023a801871382d40582c
        4500dd0c1100001e011d007251d01e20
        6e285500dd0c1100001e000000fd0032
        4b1e5111000a202020202020000000fc
        00533232443330300a202020202001a5
        020311b14690041f13120365030c0010
        00011d00bc52d01e20b8285540dd0c11
        00001e8c0ad090204031200c405500dd
        0c110000188c0ad08a20e02d10103e96
        00dd0c11000018000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000050
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

and

```
~ % sudo get-edid | parse-edid                                        
[sudo] Mot de passe de bigx : 
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
2 potential busses found: 0 3
Will scan through until the first EDID is found.
Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one.
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 0
If this isn't the EDID you were looking for, consider the other potential busses.
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "S22D300"
    ModelName "S22D300"
    VendorName "SAM"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 8 of 2016
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 480 270
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-81
    VertRefresh 50-75
    # Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x800, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz

    #Extension block found. Parsing...
    Modeline    "Mode 8" 74.25 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" 74.25 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 2" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 3" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 4" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 5" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 6" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 7" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 9" 27.00 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 10" 27.00 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync 
    Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 8"
EndSection
```

What else could I give to help you find my problem ?

**UPDATE 2 april 2017:**

I installed the missing firmwares, here is my updated modinfo:

```
~ % modinfo i915
filename:       /lib/modules/4.11.0-041100rc4-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Intel Corporation
author:         Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
firmware:       i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin
firmware:       i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin
firmware:       i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin
firmware:       i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin
firmware:       i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin
firmware:       i915/skl_guc_ver6_1.bin
firmware:       i915/kbl_huc_ver02_00_1810.bin
firmware:       i915/bxt_huc_ver01_07_1398.bin
firmware:       i915/skl_huc_ver01_07_1398.bin
...
```

My screen is still black, even during boot. My guess is some blacklisted EDID... But cannot figure it out. I tell it again, but HDMI port is OK and I can plug another screen and it works. The non working screen works OK with other computers. Cables and screen settings are OK too.

Comment: Can you use your second screen during BIOS POST? Does the GRUB menu get shown on both screens? Does the boot animation get shown on both screens? Does the login screen use both screens successfully?

Comment: Hello, no. The external screen is black during all these steps.

Comment: @xavier.seignard: can you add which screens from the `xrandr --props` are working and which aren't? I guess `HDMI-2` is the one you are having trouble with?

Comment: @SethosII yes it is HDMI-2

Comment: @xavier.seignard: what happens when you manually assign a mode like `xrandr --output "HDMI-2" --mode "1920x1080"` and what does `cvt 1920 1080` return?

Comment: I already tried it, and unfortunately, nothing happens.  Since the HDMI output works, but not the screen, I tend to think it's related to some blacklisting, maybe an EDID which is blacklisted?

Answer (score 0):

Kaby Lake has really bad support in linux 4.8. Try [installing a mainline 4.10](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Mainline-Kernel/)!

Comment: I tried 4.10 and even 4.11rc4 without any success...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have all of Intel's ***Kabylake*** firmware drivers installed. For example my system reveals:

```
$ modinfo i915
filename:       /lib/modules/4.9.17-040917-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Intel Corporation
author:         Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
firmware:       i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin
firmware:       i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin
firmware:       i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin
firmware:       i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin
firmware:       i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin
firmware:       i915/skl_guc_ver6_1.bin
srcversion:     1F29775FFDE72D1294A4A76
```

Notice how you are missing `kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin`. To get the missing drivers go to https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/firmware where you will see this screen:

[image: Intel Graphics for Linux AU bounty]

For complete download and installation instructions see [Updated kernel to 4.8 now missing firmware warnings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/updated-kernel-to-4-8-now-missing-firmware-warnings)

Comment: Hello, so I installed the missing firmwares (see my question update), and still a black screen...

Comment: If you enter `sudo find / |grep -i edid` many files will be reported. Near the end of the list there will be in some in your `/home/user/.local/share/icc/` I don't want to delete mine to see if they will be created but you might find it helpful to back them up and delete them. Just a shot in the dark mind you.

Comment: I already tried to remove icc files with no luck (btw, these files are automatically regenerated)

Comment: There is a program called `monitor-edid` I saw referenced but I don't know the ppa for it. Another program to check out is called `ddcontrol`.

Comment: No more chance...