# Installing Intel Graphics in 18.04 LTS

Tags: intel-graphics, 18.04

I just installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to a computer that has an Intel Graphics and Nvidia Graphics hardware capability. After the Ubuntu installation completed, I looked in "Additional Software" and found that only Nvidia Graphics drivers were installed. I have read that Intel has discontinued its Graphics Update tool - where can I find Intel Graphics drivers to install to my system? I would like to avoid third party PPA's if possible - does Intel maintain Graphics drivers for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Comment: The Intel i915 driver is built into the kernel.

Comment: Running "lspci | grep VGA" shows that both my Nvidia Card, and Intel Graphics processor are detected, and the xserver-xorg-video-intel package is already installed. In previous versions of Ubuntu, I've been able to choose between Nvidia and Intel graphics using Ubuntu's "Additional Software" dialog. Currently, only Nvidia's drivers are listed. How might I make sure my computer is using Intel drivers, and not Nvidia drivers?

Comment: The Ubuntu-provided Intel graphics driver (you already have it installed) should work great since they made sure it works well with the other parts of Ubuntu. Intel graphics drivers you install manually are not that well-tested and people have problems with them.

Answer (score 3):

### Switching between nVidia and Intel GPU

To activate your Intel iGPU use:

```
sudo prime-select intel
reboot
```

To turn your nVidia GPU back use:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
reboot
```

If you forget which one is running use:

```
prime-select query
```

### Skylake (i7-6700) and newer processors

The Intel iGPU driver is already built into the Linux kernel. Normally you don't have to do anything special unless you have extremely new hardware, or very old hardware. There are configuration files you may have to setup for issues such as screen tearing. If you have a Skylake or newer processor you will get warning(s) that there are additional drivers you can install: [Updated kernel to 4.8 now missing firmware warnings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/updated-kernel-to-4-8-now-missing-firmware-warnings/832528#832528) :

[image: download screen]