# Which intel graphics firmware version is in use & how to change that

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics

On ubuntu 17.10, I installed recent Intel graphics firmware:

```
skl_dmc_ver1_26
skl_guc_ver6_1
skl_huc_ver01_07_1398
```

from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/firmware using the install.sh scripts. After upgrading to ubuntu 18.04, I noticed that the newer versions of this firmware are already in /lib/firmware/i915.

Now I am not sure which firmware versions are in use - old or new?

`dmesg | grep skl_`

returns ... `skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)`

- Does this mean that the old version is in use?
- What about guc and huc?
- How do I change it to the new version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

To change the drivers in use you need to change your kernel version. However you shouldn't do this unless there are specific reasons to do so.

### Long Answer

The `install.sh` scripts have been deprecated and are no longer used. Now there are ***blobs*** (Binary Large Objects) that simply need to be downloaded and then copied to `/lib/firmware/i915`. If you follow the link you posted you will see it has been changed from the last time you downloaded.

For instructions on installing the new ***blobs*** see: [Updated kernel to 4.8 now missing firmware warnings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/updated-kernel-to-4-8-now-missing-firmware-warnings/832528#832528)

As far as quickly seeing which i915 drivers for ***Skylake*** you have installed (but not necessarily active for current boot) use:

```
$ locate i915/skl_
/lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1.bin
/lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_23.bin
/lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin
/lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver1.bin
/lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver1_1059.bin
/lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver4.bin
/lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver4_3.bin
/lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver6.bin
/lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver6_1.bin
/lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver9_33.bin
/lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_ver01_07_1398.bin
```

I noticed in your link a new version `skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin` so I downloaded it and then ran:

```
$ sudo updatedb
[sudo] password for rick:          
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ locate dmc_ver1_27
/home/rick/Downloads/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ sudo mv /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin.old
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ sudo mv /home/rick/Downloads/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k `uname -r`
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.14.42-041442-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin for module i915
Adding /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver9_33.bin
```

So even though `skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin` is available it doesn't work with the Kernel `4.14` chain and it still looks for `skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin`. Ubuntu 18.04 uses the `4.15` kernel chain so apparently it is using `skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin` as well.

---

I just downloaded Kernel 4.17 which came out two days ago and it uses the new `skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin` driver:

```
$ sudo mv /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin.old
$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k 4.17.0-041700-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.17.0-041700-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cnl_dmc_ver1_07.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_39.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver9_29.bin for module i915
Adding /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver9_33.bin
```

**Notice how it's looking for `/lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin`**

---

### Summary

- Kernel `4.14` uses `skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin`.
- Kernel `4.17` uses `skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin`.
- `/lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver9_33.bin` is used by both Kernels `4.14` and `4.17`.

You also asked: *"What about guc and huc?"* **guc** is answered immediately above. As far as **huc** is concerned the same version is used from Kernel `4.14` (and earlier) to Kernel `4.17`:

```
rick@alien:~/Downloads$ sudo mv /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_ver01_07_1398.bin /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_ver01_07_1398.bin.old
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/Downloads$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k `uname -r`
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.14.42-041442-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_ver01_07_1398.bin for module i915
Adding /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver9_33.bin
```

Comment: So there is no direct way to see what version is used (?), I have to remove the firmware from /i915, update-initramfs and look at the warnings - that's cumbersome - thank you for doing it! Seems like it would not make sense deleting the old versions when updating the kernel since they are small and useful in case I revert to the default kernel.

Comment: There probably is a way of listing what drivers are referenced by initram. The only thing I've found so far doesn't list everything: `cat /boot/initrd.img-4.14.42-041442-generic | cpio -t`

Comment: Unfortunately, this command does not list any graphics driver for kernel 4.15.