# help! W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9

Tags: drivers, upgrade, firmware, i915

I would like to know what this means and how it can be solved. I ran the following lines:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libreoffice-gtk linux-headers-4.15.0-32 linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-32-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-32-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
```

> sudo apt-get upgrade

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.12) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
```

How can it be solved?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version
Version: 1.157.20

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updated kernel to 4.8 now missing firmware warnings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/updated-kernel-to-4-8-now-missing-firmware-warnings)

Comment: Ignore it. It's not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you update *linux-firmware* to version 1.173. Please open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.173_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot and check if the error is resolved:

```
dmesg | grep -i firm
```

Comment: You don't even know if he needs those drivers.

Comment: @KenSharp I do know this: his system complains about it, my system, also using an i915 video device, does not. The *linux-firmware* package included with Ubuntu 18.04 is version 1.173 which includes those exact files: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/linux-firmware/filelist Finally, I am quite confident that after the proposed solution is implemented, the warnings will no longer appear.

Comment: My system complains and doesn't use i915. So like I said: you have no idea. You're making assumptions and wasting the user's time installing unnecessary packages.