# w: possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169

Tags: firmware

Whenever I try to install any drivers or something I get this error. Because this error I guess I am not able to on the machine. I have booted normal from recovery mode after that I have rebooted system but no luck.

```
w: possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169 
w: possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169 
i: the initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p4 
i: (uuid=827a4ecd-a3d9-4990-8a01-bb7aa2a57a22) 
i: set the resume variable to override this.
```

Comment: I've tried to edit the error message in code tags, but please elaborate where this output is from.

Comment: This is not an error. Ignore it. You can 'fix" it, but it won't change anything.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a similar bug reported here :
[Debian Bugs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=947356)

The files `rtl8125a-3.fw` and `rtl8168fp-3.fw` can be found on:

[Git Kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtl_nic/)

Then run the commands :

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/*.fw /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

The issue looks like this one :
[Possible missing frmware /lib/firmware/i915](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/possible-missing-frmware-lib-firmware-i915?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Applied for me today on Bookworm - many issues post-install of testing (using unofficial non-free installer from official list downloaded with jigdo). I had to install a kernel manually, install and run grub bootloader manually (can't do until kernel installed), then ran into this issue with missing rtl_nic firmware and initramfs attempting to resume appearing anytime I installed anything; Ultimately the `rtl_nic` directory was missing in `/lib/firmware` some of those files were directly in the firmware folder - so may have to create the `rtl_nic` directory, but issue does resolve. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Got similar error message on system with MSI MPG B550 Gaming Edge WIFI motherboard and Realtek RTL8125 2.5Gbe onboard NIC and 5.10.21 kernel (FYI: needed 5.10 kernel for proper AMD 5800X CPU and RTL8125 support):

`Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw for module r8169`

Solved it from your response - by downloading firmware files and including them into `initramfs`:

```
mkdir rtl8125b_fw
cd rtl8125b_fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw
sudo cp *.fw /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

with reboot afterwards. Didn't seen missing firmware warning anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Firmware for new Realtek Ethernet chipsets is missing in the `linux-firmware` package provided with the Ubuntu release.

It is very unlikely that you have one of these new chipsets, because your network is working.

So this warning is harmless and doesn't need any "fix".

Comment: Did you mean "harmless" instead of "harmful"?

Comment: Yep, it was a typo. Fixed. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-possible-missing-firmware-xubuntu-18-04/

```
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get -y install make gcc linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git &&
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git &&
cd rtw88/ &&
make &&

sudo make install &&
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with more firmware files on Debian 5.10 kernel.

```
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8107e-2.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8107e-1.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/tl8168fp-3.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168h-2.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168h-1.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-2.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8411-2.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8411-1.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8402-1.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-2.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-1.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-1.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw
```

And then:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/
sudo cp *.fw /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/
sudo update-initramfs -u
```