# Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware

Tags: apt, updates

While updating my Zorin 15.3 using `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` i am getting this issue

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.11) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
```

can anyone help how to fix it?

Comment: I would advise to install a regular Ubuntu and see if it happens there too. Please use https://unix.stackexchange.com/ for questions regarding zorin.  also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287896/w-possible-missing-firmware-lib-firmware-rtl-nic-rtl8125a-3-fw-for-module-r816

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Zorin forum.  (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Zorin so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)