# Old 32-bit Dell Inspiron 1300. 18.04.5 Kubuntu Installing with 3rd-party soft, LAN wire maybe fell out. Got more updates, i915 kernel module missing

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, kubuntu, dell

Wifi not working, that one time fix ill later, but now this is weird updating error and why it came, can it be because of this happened?
Posted info about comp also in answer, since was no space in question. What else is needed?

Old 32-bit Dell Inspiron 1300. 18.04.5 Kubuntu Installing with 3rd-party software, LAN wire maybe fell out. Got more updates, i915 kernel module missing.

So maybe lan wire fell out, because after install, i got no internet, plugged in, added partner repo, double checked update and dist-upgrade and got updates with this error.
Maybe in install time taking updates, something got dissconnected and not fixed automatically, so i got left with something out.

```
Setting up libcaca0:i386 (0.99.beta19-2ubuntu0.18.04.3) ...
Setting up gnupg-agent (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up aspell (0.60.7~20110707-4ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-minimal:i386 (2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up xdg-utils (1.1.2-1ubuntu2.5) ...
Setting up ca-certificates (20210119~18.04.2) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
21 added, 20 removed; done.
Setting up dirmngr (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up bluez (5.48-0ubuntu3.7) ...
Setting up libgs9:i386 (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.18.04.15) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-bin (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.9) ...
Setting up libexif12:i386 (0.6.21-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2~18.04.6) ...
Setting up libc-ares2:i386 (1.14.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.173.20) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-94-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
Setting up libwhoopsie0:i386 (0.2.62ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up libmysofa0:i386 (0.6~dfsg0-3+deb10u1build1) ...
Setting up liblwres160:i386 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.16) ...
Setting up rfkill (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7) ...
Setting up libx11-data (2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 (2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up python3-distupgrade (1:18.04.45) ...
Setting up gpg (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.4) ...
```

And in end also.

```
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Processing triggers for plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text (1:18.04ubuntu11) ...
dpkg: warning: version '/etc/lsb-release' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
rmdir: failed to remove '/lib/plymouth/': No such file or directory
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for rsyslog (8.32.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for dictionaries-common (1.27.2) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20210119~18.04.2) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
done.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.13) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-94-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
produktivitate@produktivitate-ME051:~$
```

lspci -nn -d 14e4:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)
02:03.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/PM/GMS/910GML Express Processor to DRAM Controller (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #4 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev d3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FBM (ICH6M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) IDE Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
02:03.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)
```

dmesg

```
[    3.824367] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[   22.491113] input: HDA Intel Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
[   22.491406] input: HDA Intel Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[   22.630159] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4318 WLAN found (core revision 9)
[   22.677124] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 3, Type 2 (G), Revision 7
[   22.677149] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2050, Revision 8, Version 0
[   22.693320] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode5.fw failed with error -2
[   22.693365] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode5.fw failed with error -2
[   22.693412] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode5.fw failed with error -2
[   22.693446] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode5.fw failed with error -2
[   22.693451] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode5.fw" not found
[   22.693458] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode5.fw" not found
[   22.693461] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.                                                                                                                                       
[   22.693545] Broadcom 43xx driver loaded [ Features: PNL ]
[   72.320791] random: crng init done
[   72.320798] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[  109.165301] b44 ssb1:0 eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
[  109.165307] b44 ssb1:0 eth0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
[  109.165457] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

lshw

```
produktivitate-me051
    description: Portable Computer
    product: ME051
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    serial: 3BZ1L2J
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.3 dmi-2.3
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=portable uuid=44454C4C-4200-105A-8031-B3C04F4C324A
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 0RJ272
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       serial: .3BZ1L2J.CN7016668T098J.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: A10
          date: 11/07/2006
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 448KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb agp smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Celeron(R) M processor         1.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 400
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.13.8
          slot: Microprocessor
          size: 1600MHz
          capacity: 2130MHz
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 133MHz
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss tm pbe nx bts cpuid pti
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 700
             size: 8KiB
             capacity: 8KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back data
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 701
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             clock: 66MHz (15.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies unified
             configuration: level=2
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 1000
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2560MiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 533 MHz (1,9 ns)
             vendor: Nanya Technology
             physical id: 0
             serial: 35533A34
             slot: DIMM_A
             size: 512MiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 667 MHz (1,5 ns)
             vendor: 7F7F7F7FCB000000
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000000
             slot: DIMM_B
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Mobile 915GM/PM/GMS/910GML Express Processor to DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 03
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display:0
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:dff00000-dff7ffff ioport:eff8(size=8) memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:dfec0000-dfefffff memory:c0000-dffff
        *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Display controller
             product: Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:dff80000-dfffffff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:24 memory:dfebc000-dfebffff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:80000000-801fffff ioport:80200000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:dfc00000-dfdfffff ioport:d0000000(size=2097152)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:16 ioport:bf80(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.4.0-94-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.04
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:17 ioport:bf60(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.4.0-94-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 5.04
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:18 ioport:bf40(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.4.0-94-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 5.04
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.3
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:19 ioport:bf20(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.4.0-94-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@5
                logical name: usb5
                version: 5.04
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:b0000000-b00003ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.4.0-94-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: d3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
             resources: memory:dfb00000-dfbfffff
           *-network:0
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
                vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 02
                serial: 00:15:c5:6d:6d:a3
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=b44 driverversion=2.0 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.138 latency=64 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:18 memory:dfbfc000-dfbfdfff
           *-network:1
                description: Network controller
                product: BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller
                vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
                physical id: 3
                bus info: pci@0000:02:03.0
                version: 02
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master
                configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=64
                resources: irq:17 memory:dfbfe000-dfbfffff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 82801FBM (ICH6M) LPC Interface Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) IDE Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.1
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ide isa_compatibility_mode_controller__supports_both_channels_switched_to_pci_native_mode__supports_bus_mastering bus_master
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
             resources: irq:16 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:bfa0(size=16)
     *-scsi
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: SSDPR-CX400-128
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 61.3
             serial: GUH032110
             size: 119GiB (128GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=a35ac005
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: 3.1
                serial: d085-4743
                size: 48MiB
                capacity: 50MiB
                capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2022-01-15 14:50:48 filesystem=ntfs label=System Reserved modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: 3.1
                serial: ae10561c-9b24-e74e-be6c-b7d3f60179f0
                size: 65GiB
                capacity: 65GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2022-01-15 14:50:55 filesystem=ntfs label=Windows Pro modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 3.1
                serial: 14c1-032e
                size: 429MiB
                capacity: 450MiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2022-01-16 01:58:12 filesystem=ntfs modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:3
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                size: 53GiB
                capacity: 53GiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   logical name: /
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 8c2d7681-4766-4186-bb7a-845993d56fb2
                   size: 53GiB
                   capacity: 53GiB
                   capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2022-01-15 18:10:28 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2022-01-15 18:32:23 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2022-01-15 18:32:24 state=mounted
  *-battery
       product: DELLYD1205A2
       vendor: SMP
       physical id: 1
       slot: Sys. Battery Bay
       capacity: 44000mWh
       configuration: voltage=11,1V
```

Followed instructions of debugging ubuntu lspci and others from [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into)

`lspci -vvv` output is at https://pastebin.com/raw/UEKf9fnD

Comment: All "W:"s are just warnings, you can ignore it. Probably you need to install `firmware-b43-installer` and `broadcom-sta-dkms` packages for Wi-Fi support.

Comment: @N0rbert that, thouse 2 packages, didnt change anything still after reboot. Still no wifi. Found also b43-fwcutter for 32-bit. But why after installing and downloading all, i still had kilogram of updates available? Maybe since checkmarked one more apt list, i think universe or something that was available. So now my lan also was not working, removed all except 32 bit b43-fwcutter i left. But nothing of this gave wifi, only lan showed red. Made 2 reboots. Then removed b43 64 bit packages. Got back lan. Theres also firmware-b43legacy-installer. Ill try to isolate what could get wifi.

Comment: @N0rbert also with all thouse packs installed- still have thouse errors. Even 2x, for each of cureently installed 2 kernels. This needs to be fixed in gnu/linux debian ubuntu

Comment: Unfortunately, Kubuntu 18.04 is [EOL](https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-reaches-end-of-kubuntu-support/). I'm surprised this hasn't been closed already.

Comment: @KGIII this how applies to this forum depending of EOL? even on support sites this is important and valid and fixable. Also this is 32-bit last 18.04 version. So its even more important to have fix for all old laptop that dont have 64 bits to have them usable not only for EOL but for Ubuntu LTS versions still 18.04 goes mid 2022, so need 2 fix, so people who dont use google can have good experience 2 fix bug #1 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1 , and paid ESM 5 more years. https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle . This isnt ubuntu website, & even on ubuntu websites still should be fixed.

Comment: Kubuntu 18.04 LTS is EOL as are all *flavors* with 18.04; as the last [18.04.6 release annoucement](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/) states "*Maintenance updates will be provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, and Ubuntu Base*." where you'll note no *flavors* are mentioned being EOL already. Your question is on-topic here as covered by Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with KDE (not *really* Kubuntu as it's EOL).  FYI: This also isn't a forum, but a Q&A site (https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the Ubuntu Forums)

Comment: Harware and packages can be used in any ver if fixed, so needs a automatic harware detection solution. Same package exists ready for next version, that trying to make perfect until locking, freezing EOL. Release cycle website shows free EOL will be 2023. Doesnt mean people need to stop using or having it as frozen ready to use out-of-box working 1st installation where things are already fixed for this 18.04 last 32-bit premade version. Otherwise i have learned a lot with ubuntu, but will need to go to debian, that doesnt have installation version restrictions. PS. Kubuntu needs then 32 18.04.6

Comment: You didn't read well; eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ states "*Maintenance updates will be provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, and Ubuntu Base. All the remaining flavours will be supported for 3 years*".  Five years didn't ever include *flavors*, all were 3 years many cycles ago but only 'main' repository software was extended to 5 years, ie. Ubuntu Desktop/Server etc but not flavors where packages are found in 'universe'. You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to get details on what is supported/isn't for your actual install

Comment: Ah, im just about that package will be existing in 20.04 and new ones still and that age is still valid, not so much about when, since now when im reporting this bug, then its still in LTS. But beeing precise im now reading again and so i think they mean not that from that post time 2020 + 5 years but changing from 3 to 5 years? Anyways still need to make this harware detectable and installable out of box or asking to install if detected. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1958038 ah, so command tells total 5 years, so even for distro still valid till 2023. 1288 (58.7%) packages supported.

Comment: 5 year support included packages only on installation media of Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, and Ubuntu Base; ie. no 'universe' packages are included there. Universe packages have variable support lives (why Ubuntu media does **not** have it enabled by default) as package supported life in 'universe' can be 9-36 months supported (Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was **not** a LTS release thus only had 9 months of supported life; *Lubuntu Next* 18.04 with LXQt too had 9 months; only Lubuntu with LXDE was 3 years...    All 'main' repo packages have 5 years; all flavor packages did not

Comment: Ah, so i found some command sudo apt policy packagename also then installers are then firmware-b43-installer and firmware-b43legacy-installer are multiverse, so can report and someone or if i learn, can make updates or new pack, & b43-fwcutter is in main, so then canonical engineers route debian packages to ubuntu main for LTS? I need all verses to be enabled allways. Im ok if i get warning messege on each install that maybe some support might not be anymore. Even with automatic pushing to each system latest code difference update packages. Why should even some verse be there, but not enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Ah so in errors is help. Update showing.

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_04.bin for module i915
```

And dmesg showing where is command `modprobe b43` in https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware
http://linuxwireless.sipsolutions.net/en/users/Drivers/b43/

So need to have errors with help to come up.
Also need errors that come up, auto fixes this when getting info about firmware.

```
[   22.693320] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode5.fw failed with error -2
[   22.693365] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode5.fw failed with error -2
[   22.693412] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode5.fw failed with error -2
[   22.693446] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode5.fw failed with error -2
[   22.693451] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode5.fw" not found
[   22.693458] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode5.fw" not found
[   22.693461] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.                                                                                                                                       
[   22.693545] Broadcom 43xx driver loaded [ Features: PNL ]
```

Looks like for me worked only this and reboot

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

it also installed the `b43-fwcutter`

maybe some need `sudo apt install firmware-b43legacy-installer`

then commands `b43-fwcutter` to see commands, but i used only `b43-fwcutter -l` to see list but didnt import them

Tested doing modprobe -r b43 and reinstalling 1st package all works on restart.
 <strike>Looks like in end also need, at one point i did it since i didint checked if it added firmware to modprobe automatically, if not, then can try</strike>

```
modprobe b43
```

maybe again

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

reboot to check, since can show here still errors, but wifi maybe is already installed.